# LinkedList pop and push

Tags: java, linked-list

Can anyone understand the cause of this error? I guess I mixed up the stack and the list. What can I use instead of "pop"? What is your suggestion?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(
```

Code :

```
public class PostfixHesaplama {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String giris="231*+9-"; 
    System.out.println("postfix evaluation: "+postfix(giris));    

}
static int postfix(String giris) 
{ 
    //create a stack 
    List<Integer> list1=new LinkedList<>(); 

    // Scan all characters one by one 
    for(int i=0;i<giris.length();i++) 
    { 
        char c=giris.charAt(i); 

        // If the scanned character is an operand (number here), 
        // push it to the stack. 
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) 
        list1.add(c - '0'); 

        //  If the scanned character is an operator, pop two 
        // elements from stack apply the operator 
        else
        { 
            int val1 = list1.remove(i); 
            int val2 = list1.remove(i); 

            switch(c) 
            { 
                case '+': 
                list1.add(val2+val1); 
                break; 

                case '-': 
                list1.add(val2- val1); 
                break; 

                case '/': 
                list1.add(val2/val1); 
                break; 

                case '*': 
                list1.add(val2*val1); 
                break; 
          } 
        } 
    } 
    return list1.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push and pop you are better served by a [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). However, I think your problem is `remove(i)`. You probably want to use pop (or removeLast?) instead.

If you stay with LinkedList, use addLast/removeLast or addFirst/removeFirst.

Comment: Perhaps ArrayDeque would be better. The docs seem to indicate that it's performance is better than both Stack and Queue. The docs for stack even suggest using a Deque over Stack

Answer (score 0):

your problem is from from 2nd remove(i). You are trying to remove object twice from the same position(Note: i is not getting decremented. Its having same value). you should use remove(i-1) for the 2nd remove.
Current Code Segement:

```
 int val1 = list1.remove(i); 
 int val2 = list1.remove(i);
```

It should be:

```
 int val1 = list1.remove(i); 
 int val2 = list1.remove(i-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Add LinkedList declaration and use removeLast():

```
LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < giris.length(); i++) {
  char c = giris.charAt(i);

  if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    list1.add(c - '0');
  } else {
    int val1 = list1.removeLast();
    int val2 = list1.removeLast();

    switch (c) {
      case '+':
        list1.add(val2 + val1);
        break;

      case '-':
         list1.add(val2 - val1);
         break;

      case '/':
        list1.add(val2 / val1);
        break;

      case '*':
        list1.add(val2 * val1);
        break;
    }
  }
}
return list1.removeLast();
```